# iOS WebService to comunicate with ASP server

Tags: asp.net, ios, web-services, frameworks, asmx

I have a webservice (.asmx) hosted on an ASP server with which i would like to communicate using SOAP from an iOS application.

For some functions, the server returns primitives, structures and datasets (as in system.data.dataset).

Can you please recommend me a framework that will manage the communications and XML parsing for me?

What kind of class should I use to emulate a dataset, or would I need to make one of my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your connections try this framework:  http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

However apples NSURLConnection api is pretty good and easy to use.

For easy XML parsing try: https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML

Hope this helps :)

Sam

Comment: Thank you for your response. ASIHTTPRequest will come in handy. As for TouchXML, i found a small XML parser that does a great job constructing the items into an NSDictionary tree.